# how to calculate f+ without using Armstrong's axioms

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

i want to know if there is an algorithm for computing f+ without using Armstrong's axioms.
If not, does computing all possible dependencies closure gives f+?
For instance using these relation and functional dependencies  :
    R=(C,T,H,R,S,G)
    F=(C->T, HR->C, HT->R, CS->G, HS->R)
does computing C+,T+,H+,R+,S+,G+,CT+,CH+, CR+... will finally gives f+?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

computing each closure of attribute in the left side X of the dependency will give you f+ by 
**X -> X+**, but usually you wont be needed to compute all f+, you will need just to find if a dependency is there or not.

Comment: what do you mean by  X -> X+.
could you give a small example on how to do it by using all possible dependencies?

Comment: as you did, every attribute you wrote with + should be on the left and its closure on the right: example X = C: C -> C+ (C -> CT)

Comment: F+ contains dependencies and not attributes, that is why you need to compute dependencies and not just attributes